# Fluent API mapping other side if a 1-1 relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a relationship set up between 2 tables using code first and Fluent API. This works and the schema is generated with the correct fields and key assignments. However, my problem is I need to be able to say SupplyPoint.SupplyPointPricing in my resultant Model. What I have below only gives me the other way around.

I figure there must be a way to keep the structure I have but just MAP SupplyPoint.

```
   public partial class SupplyPoint
    {

        [Key]
        public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }
        public string SupplyPointName { get; set; }


    }
    public class SupplyPointPricing
    {
        public int SupplyPointPricingId { get; set; }
        public int? SupplyPointId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SupplyPointId")]
        public virtual SupplyPoint SupplyPoint { get; set; }

    }
```

Then I use Fluent API and this gives me the 1-1 between the tables and the Schema I expect

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<SupplyPointPricing>()
      .HasOptional(a => a.SupplyPoint)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(u => u.SupplyPointId);
```

*Last time I had this problem I had to change the design around and have a foreign key in the SupplyPoint table. On that previous occasion that was OK since it was a 1-1 required where there are always a matching record. This time around I need to keep this structure since there is 1-0 between SupplyPoint and SupplyPointPricing.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have always done 1-to-1 relationships with my models, without using Fluent mapping:

```
public partial class SupplyPoint
{
    [Key]
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }

    public virtual SupplyPointPricing SupplyPointPricing { get; set; }
}

public class SupplyPointPricing
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("SupplyPoint")]
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }

    public virtual SupplyPoint SupplyPoint { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the `SupplyPointPricing` does not have an Id of its own, but only the Id of the SupplyPoint, which acts as a key in the 1-to-1 relatioship.

The only thing I'm not sure of is if the `SupplyPointId` can be a nullable int.

This will not create a foreign key on the SupplyPoint, so if you don't have a Pricing, the `SupplyPoint.SupplyPointPricing` property will be null.